What's the point of registering with "Agence pour la Protection des Programmes" (Software Protection Agency) in addition to pushing the code to GitHub
I read the following in this license in a github.com repo:

This software has been registered with "Agence pour la Protection des Programmes" (Software Protection Agency) by Inria and Adobe (registration ID: IDDN.FR.001.200019.000.S.P.2024.000.31235).

Assume that a program's source code was placed on github.com. What's the point of registering a program with the "Agence pour la Protection des Programmes" (Software Protection Agency) in addition to pushing its code to github.com?
"What's the point" = any form of potential legal upside.

The Agency says:

Le droit d’auteur protège vos créations numériques. Cependant, en cas de contestation de vos droits ou de contrefaçon, la difficulté sera d’en apporter la preuve. L’œuvre numérique est par nature complexe, composite et très évolutive. Les contentieux peuvent remonter à des faits générateurs datant de plusieurs années. Il est difficile de « réécrire l’histoire » de façon certaine devant l’autorité judiciaire car il faut que les éléments de l’époque soient conservés sans aucune possibilité de manipulation ultérieure et datés de façon certaine
Contrairement à l’idée répandue, un logiciel seul ne peut être breveté en Europe... . Dès lors, le dépôt à l’APP est une étape essentielle pour protéger vos créations numériques. Il vous permet de pré-constituer la preuve de vos droits.

The Agency itself describes its repository as a tool that can assist in proving the provenance of software works.
"What's the point" depends on what one is trying to accomplish. My understanding is that git (and GitHub, which is a proprietary interface to git repositories) do not assure that dates have not been altered. The Agency says it provides this assurance. Depending on the fact at issue in litigation, the Agency repository might have greater evidentiary value.

Thanks! ""What's the point" depends on what one is trying to accomplish" -> any form of potential legal upside.
